# How to remove some specfic navigation links only from selected page/pages?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, menus, navigation

For example:

In the client site I have 5 page 1) Home 2) product 3) Services 4) Contact us 5) Blog

Only from the blog page I want to remove 2) product and 3) Services but not from other pages.

Is there any Plugin to do this?

Comment: Is it a problem if you have to create the menu twice? Once the full menu, and once for the blog pages? It's very easy to define two menus, and show one of them depending on the page you are on.

Comment: would this help ? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/

Comment: no it's exclude page for navigation for each page

Comment: @Jan Fabry - How to DO thAT?

Answer (score 1):

You can register multiple menus, and display one of them depending on the context.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => 'Regular',
    'blog' => 'Blog',
) );
```

[image]

Then in your theme, you select the menu you want:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => (is_page() ? 'primary' : 'blog'),
     'menu_id' => 'nav'
) );
```

Comment: But in my admin "Heade" and "Footer" navigation showing, not regular and blog http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5017/5389285912_c40b6f934e.jpg

Comment: And I don't want 2 menu at same page. I need different top navigation for "Blog" page and for any page comes under blog/

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: You don't have to use two menus on the same page. The idea is that you create multiple *potential* menus in the admin area, and then in your template you choose which one to display via the `theme_location` parameter.

Comment: "in your template you choose which one to display via the theme_location parameter" How to do this , please tell.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: As I said: with the `theme_location` parameter. With `register_nav_menus()` you register multiple menus, where the key of the array is the `theme_location`. With the `wp_nav_menu` you can specify which of these menus you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

> use conditional tags like

```
if(is_single()) 
SOME_MENU 
else
OTHER_MENU
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your page links are added. Are they listed through wp_list_pages()? Manually?

Regardless of how you've done it, you will be able to exclude particular page links on certain pages by using conditional tags.

For example:

```
if (!is_page('contact-us'))
{
// pages to list when not on the contact page
}
```

Comment: you mean I will have to make different template for the page and add this code

Comment: Menu is created by Wordpress 3.0 Menu http://templatic.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/menu_ui_active.gif

Comment: I think you can add that code to the header, actually.

Comment: @Lynne - what i need to put inside {
// pages to list when not on the contact page
}
 and how?

Comment: Ah, as you're using the 3.0 menu system, this is a much more difficult task.